# rotate (orbit) node around another object (javafx-2)

Tags: rotation, javafx-2

i'm having troubles to create a simple sun / earth kind of animation.
In the following example the circle should orbit around the rectangle.
For that i create a new group, attach the rectangle with offset 0 and the circle at offset 50.
Now when the Group is rotated i thought the rectangle should rotate around itself, and the circle should orbit around the rectangle.

But it seems both shapes have an offset and rotate around a invisible center.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // create root node
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // translate root node to center of the screen
        root.setTranslateX(320);
        root.setTranslateY(200);

        // create scene
        createScene(root);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void createScene(Group root) {
        Group branch = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(branch);

        // create a recangle, which will be added to the branch
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(40, 20);
        branch.getChildren().add(r);

        // circle should orbit around the rectangle
        Circle c = new Circle(10);
        branch.getChildren().add(c);
        c.setTranslateY(-50);

        // rotate the branch
        Timeline rot = new Timeline();
        rot.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rot.setRate(1);
        rot.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(
                        branch.rotateProperty(), 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(branch
                        .rotateProperty(), 360)));
        rot.playFromStart();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: For some background information, here is a [small interactive sample](https://gist.github.com/1475424) of modifying various JavaFX rotation parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that rotating of any object happens around its center. The easiest way to fix your issues would be using StackPane instead of Group. StackPane puts all object to it's center by default.

```
private void createScene(Group root) {
    Pane branch = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(branch);
```

Comment: cool thanks, that works. i will read up on the difference between those types.